# Android Add two surface view to single Layout

Tags: android, surfaceview

Probably my question might be silly. I posted to know whether there is a possibilities to add two surfaceview object under a Relativelayout.

I need One surface view to stream Video behind and another view do sprite animations.

I tried putting them under a relative layout but the surfaceview i put first on layout takes preference and second view disappears.

Kindly suggest me a solution.

**EDIT :**

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/widget31"
android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <LinearLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/widget30" android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>
     <com.mycalss.CameraView
    android:id="@+id/camerapreview" android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:focusable="true"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Now i add my graphic's surfaceview inside linearlayout-widget30 in code

Comment: You should be able to do what you're attempting. Can you post your current layout file?

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be properly sizing your Views: try setting the `layout_height` of both to 0dp and then setting the `layout_weight` of both to 1 and see if they both show up.